# Recursively report the sum of the list if it contains exactly 3 odd numbers

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I am new to haskell.I am trying to create a function that recursively report the sum of the list.Can sb help me?

Comment: FYI, haskell has built in `even` and `odd` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension has another syntax:

```
[expr | x <- xs, ...]
```

So in your case:

```
function xs = if length xs' == 3 then sum xs else (length xs' - length xs'') where
    xs' = [x | x <- xs, mod x 2 == 1]
    xs'' = [x | x <- xs, mod x 2 == 0]
```

But you can use function `partition` to get `xs'` and `xs''` at once:

```
(xs', xs'') = partition (\x -> mod x 2 == 1) xs
```

As mentioned in comments, it's not recursive. The idea of solution is in @michal-gajda answer: go over list and collect number of odds, evens and sum. At the end make a decision:

```
function = go 0 0 0 where -- same as function xs = go 0 0 0 xs
    go odds evens s [] = if odds == 3 then s else odds - evens
    go odds evens s (x:xs)
        | odd x = go (odds + 1) evens (s + x) xs
        | otherwise = go odds (evens + 1) (s + x) xs
```

Comment: I don't believe his teacher will accept this as a recursive solution.

Comment: @changed Can you provide an alternative recursive solution if possible?

Comment: @changed, well, i agree :) it's not recursive

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use internal function `go`, that recursively accumulates three results:

1. Number of odds in the list.
2. Number of evens in the list.
3. Sum of the list.

Then, when the list is empty, you decide what to return:

```
finalStep (odds, evens, sum) | odds == 3 = sum
                             | otherwise = odds-evens
```